# how to replace repetition in regex?

Tags: java, regex

Say that I have the folowing regex:

```
(\*(.*)_(.*)){1,10}
```

to find this words

```
*word1_word2 *word3_word4 *word5_word6 ...
```

I'm trying to replace this words, so I get the folowing result:

```
word1="word2" word3="word4" word5="word6"
```

But I can't find a way to replace using $, because I can't get every single repetition.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Get rid of `{1,10}`. Use your regex to find single pair, and decide how it should be replaced. Let regex engine iterate over entire text to find all pairs and replace them accordingly. Also `.*` is not good idea. Use something more specific, which will not represent entire text, maybe `\S*` (zero or more non-whitespace).

Comment: You can use `str=str.replaceAll("\\*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9]+)", "$1=\"$2\"");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\*([^_\s]*)_([^_\s]*)
```

or

```
\*([^_\s]*)_(\S*)
```

and replace with `$1="$2"`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QOKTH9/1/)

**Details**

- `\*` - a `*`
- `([^_\s]*)`  - Group 1: 0+ chars other than whitespace and `_`
- `_` - a `_`
- `([^_\s]*)`  - Group 2: 0+ chars other than whitespace and `_` or
- `\S*` - zero or more non-whitespace chars.